# Unable to apply visibility in indeterminate mode for progressbar angular2 material

Tags: angular, angular2-material

```
 <md-progress-bar color="warn" mode="indeterminate" [class.hide]="visible"></md-progress-bar>
```

Angular2 material 2.0.0-beta.1

https://plnkr.co/edit/sHtce9IcdCXuLb8kPhgr?p=preview

***I raised an issue in the angular2 material, it was resolved and pushed the changes to master branch. 
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2413
If anybody experiencing the same issue with beta.1 release please use the 
npm install https://github.com/angular/material2-builds.git to resolve this behavior***

Comment: What about the `[hidden]` directive?

Comment: @echonax tried but not working.

Comment: I raised an issue in the angular2 material, it was resolved and pushed the changes to master branch. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2413 If annbody experiencing the same issue with beta.1 release please use the npm install https://github.com/angular/material2-builds.git to resolve this behavior

Comment: Before down voting look at the plnkr sample which I have already shared and please share the mistakes in the sample so that will get some better idea. As I mentioned in this particular scenario, it is happening only with the progress bar with indeterminate state not  with other state or other control.

Answer (score 3):

You can surround the bar with a div if you don't want to install again. like below

```
 <div  [hidden]="showLoading">
<md-progress-bar
  mode="indeterminate"
  aria-label="Loading"></md-progress-bar></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) is the way to go.  Verified on Angular 8

```
<mat-progress-bar [color]="'warn'"
                  [mode]="'indeterminate'"
                  [ngStyle]="{'visibility':mainFrameLoading==true ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}">
</mat-progress-bar>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [hidden] directive that receives a Boolean value.

for example:

```
[hidden]="true"
```

Comment: I raised an issue in the angular2 material, it was resolved and pushed the changes to master branch. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/2413 If annbody experiencing the same issue with beta.1 release please use the npm install https://github.com/angular/material2-builds.git to resolve this behavior

Answer (score 0):

use *ngIf

```
 <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="isHidden"></mat-progress-bar>
```